# run a runnable jobs at a particular time in multithreaded way

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, priority-queue

I am working on below interview question:

> A server receives requests from different clients. Each client send a
>   Runnable job and time on which this job should be run. Write a java
>   program that would accept these jobs and run each job at the required
>   time.

I am not able to figure out how to solve this problem. Maybe we can have priority queue to hold the jobs and it should be multithreaded. One thread should accept the tasks, the other one should run the jobs. I can think of using some queue like `DelayQueue` but not sure how to implement it..

Can anyone provide an example on how should I implement this?

Comment: were they asking for a program like in code, or approach because the above thing can be easily solved using 2 different services.

Comment: A ScheduledExecutorService uses a DelayQueue